# error when compile opencv in qt applying tbb

Tags: qt, opencv, tbb

I Have the following issue when compiling opencv project in qt applying tbb

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libtbb.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib
Reason: image not found
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

Can any friend tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Add it as an answer or delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I suddenly solved this problem by copy the libtbb.dylib to /usr/local/lib/ folder.

Thank

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you are running your application it can't find the libraries to load. You need to set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to point to the directory containing this library in your application scheme.

Product > Edit Scheme > Environment Variables