# OpenCV facemorpher 1.0.1 error: no image output, missing library?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, dyld

I'm working on a project using openCV and Python to create average faces from an image database. I installed openCV 3.0.0, CMake, and all the python packages to use this
[facemorpher 1.0.1 python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/facemorpher/1.0.1#pip-library)

I get this command line error when I run 'python facemorpher/averager.py --images=IMFDB_final/Ali/HelloBrother/images --out=testmorph.jpg'

my directory has the IMFDB folder within 'face_morpher' folder.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_videostab.2.4.dylib
Referenced from:  /Users/Megan/Documents/face_morpher/facemorpher/bin/stasm_util
Reason: image not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "facemorpher/averager.py", line 94, in <module>
args['--out'], args['--plot'])
   File "facemorpher/averager.py", line 61, in averager
img, points = load_image_points(path, size)
 File "facemorpher/averager.py", line 47, in load_image_points
points = locator.face_points(path)
File "/Users/Megan/Documents/face_morpher/facemorpher/locator.py", line 34, in face_points
   s = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
 File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command   '"/Users/Megan/Documents/face_morpher/facemorpher/bin/stasm_util" -f "/Users/Megan/Documents/face_morpher/facemorpher/data" "IMFDB_final/Ali/HelloBrother/images/Ali_1.jpg"' returned non-zero exit status -5
```

EDIT:
i have the  `libopencv_videostab.3.0.dylib` file within my virtual environment.
would the issue be resolved by uninstalling openCV 3.0 and installing 2.4 instead?

Comment: This could help: [error-when-compile-opencv-in-qt-applying-tbb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982736/error-when-compile-opencv-in-qt-applying-tbb)

Comment: so i would copy the missing library into facemorpher/bin/, or into /face_morpher?

Answer (score 0):

if your virtual environment OS is linux, try copying libopencv_videostab.2.4.dylib in /usr/local/lib/ If the OS is Windows, try adding a new [environment variable](https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500) with the variable_name = "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" and in the value, the absolute path to the folder containing the libopencv_videostab.2.4.dylib library.