# ImportError: Could not import the Python Imaging Library (PIL) required to load image files

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to run the average.py program in the facemorpher 1.0.1 python package. I have created a virtual environment that has openCV installed with homebrew, python 2.7 installed in homebrew, and executable `frameworkpython` that makes a framework build of python inside the virtual environment `cv`.

running the average program currently gives me this output.

```
(cv) Francess-MacBook-Pro-2:face_morpher Megan$ frameworkpython facemorpher/averager.py --images=IMFDB_final/Ali/HelloBrother/images --out=average.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "facemorpher/averager.py", line 94, in <module>
    args['--out'], args['--plot'])
File "facemorpher/averager.py", line 61, in averager
    img, points = load_image_points(path, size)
File "facemorpher/averager.py", line 46, in load_image_points
    img = scipy.ndimage.imread(path)[..., :3]
 File "/Users/Megan/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/io.py", line 25, in imread
raise ImportError("Could not import the Python Imaging Library (PIL)"
ImportError: Could not import the Python Imaging Library (PIL) required to load image files.  Please refer to http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL/ for installation instructions.
```

Can I install Pillow to fix this error, and where should i install my PIL or Pillow path to fix this?

Comment: Did you try pip install Pillow from within your virtualenv?

Comment: just did! now i have a different error, but at least that one is gone.

Answer (score 4):

resolved by doing `pip install Pillow` in the virtual env folder. now back to error found  at [OpenCV facemorpher 1.0.1 error: no image output, missing library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532101/opencv-facemorpher-1-0-1-error-no-image-output-missing-library)