# ImportError: Could not import the Python Imaging Library (PIL) required to load image files on tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

I am doing a deep learning course on udacity. For the first assignment whenI tried to run the script which is below the problem 1 , I got this error. So I tried to uninstall PIL and pillow and then installed these individually but I didnot succeeded.
I need help guy. I am using tensorflow docker image with python notebook.

```
# These are all the modules we'll be using later. Make sure you can import them
# before proceeding further.
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import scipy
import tarfile
from IPython.display import display, Image
from scipy import ndimage
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlretrieve
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
# Config the matplotlib backend as plotting inline in IPython
%matplotlib inline 

url = 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/books1000/'
last_percent_reported = None

def download_progress_hook(count, blockSize, totalSize):
    percent = int(count * blockSize * 100 / totalSize)

   if last_percent_reported != percent:
     if percent % 5 == 0:
  sys.stdout.write("%s%%" % percent)
  sys.stdout.flush()
else:
  sys.stdout.write(".")
  sys.stdout.flush()

last_percent_reported = percent
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/1_notmnist.ipynb

You can see the code here. I got error in the code block after problem 1
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSRvK.jpg)

I tried each and everything describe here in these two links or solutions:

[Solution 1 on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534220/importerror-could-not-import-the-python-imaging-library-pil-required-to-load)

[Solution 2 on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720968/pil-importerror-the-imaging-extension-was-built-for-another-version-of-pillow)

Operating System:

using docker and tensorflow is installed in a container with IPython notebook.

The output from python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.**version**)".

0.11.0

Comment: Did you install PIL ? If not, follow the link in the error message

Comment: @lhk Yes I did and it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 71):

`pip install pillow`

Then replace 
`from IPython.display import display, Image`
with
`from IPython.display import display`
`from PIL import Image`

Comment: don't forget to restart you env after pip install.., like: source deactivate;  source activate.., etc.

Answer (score 15):

I met the same problem. But I am using a different setting for the tensorflow. OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Installation using Anaconda. 
I solved it by following the warnings in [Pillow installation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). It may not be useful for a docker installation of tensorflow though.

Here are the steps I did. First enter the tensorflow environment,

```
source activate tensorflow
```

Then uninstall PIL and install Pillow

```
conda uninstall PIL
conda install Pillow
```

Then in the provided code, replace

```
from IPython.display import display, Image
```

by

```
from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image
```

That's all. Re-run the code and it works without PIL error.

Comment: Note: you might need to restart spyder for the change to take effect. (Thanks SanjeevKumar for pointing this out!)

Comment: Thank You. I learning Artifficial Intelligence in Udemy and in the class 255 i got this situation. I using Ubuntu 16.04. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by uninstalling Jupyter and re-installed it properly. The problem was linked to the notebook kernel. My terminal and my notebook didn't have the same kernel.
To check it, I did in my virtualenv:

`jupyter-kernelspec list`

then go to your kernel directories lists and open the json file (something like `/Library/Jupyter/kernels/virtualenv/kernel.json`)

and check than the Python link is the same than in the output of 
`which python`.

If not, create another kernel for your virtualenv.

Comment: This answer got me a good portion of the way there.  To create another kernel for my virtualenv, I had to refer to this document, http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html, the "Kernels for Different Environments" section.

Answer (score 1):

As for Windows users who use Anaconda, there is likely a simple solution to your problem. If you've installed 'tensorflow' with pip, or a pip variant (ie. pip3), then you will have to install tensorflow again, but this time with the command `conda install tensorflow`.

Comment: Does this install the CPU or GPU variant?

Answer (score -2):

Install `PIL` in anaconda, then:

```
from PIL import Image
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000 // batch_size,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800 // batch_size)
model.save_weights('first_try.h5') 

output will display like: Epoch 1/50
 34/125 [=======>......................] - ETA: 7:23 - loss: 0.7237 - acc: 0.5478 ... comntinue
```