# ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library

This is very tricky. I have almost tried all solutions on the internet but still can't solve this problem.

If I simply type

```
from PIL import ImageFile
print(Image.__file__)
```

Everything seems work fine and the system will print

```
C:\Users\BenWang\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py
```

Like this

But in my coding, if I use the following code:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True                 

train_tensors = paths_to_tensor(train_files).astype('float32')/255
valid_tensors = paths_to_tensor(valid_files).astype('float32')/255
test_tensors = paths_to_tensor(test_files).astype('float32')/255
```

The error will appear something like this:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-166-10a043c54408> in <module>()
      4 
      5 
----> 6 train_tensors = paths_to_tensor(train_files).astype('float32')/255
      7 valid_tensors = paths_to_tensor(valid_files).astype('float32')/255
      8 test_tensors = paths_to_tensor(test_files).astype('float32')/255

<ipython-input-149-36af157e68bd> in paths_to_tensor(img_paths)
     11 
     12 def paths_to_tensor(img_paths):
---> 13     list_of_tensors = [path_to_tensor(img_path) for img_path in tqdm(img_paths)]
     14     return np.vstack(list_of_tensors)

<ipython-input-149-36af157e68bd> in <listcomp>(.0)
     11 
     12 def paths_to_tensor(img_paths):
---> 13     list_of_tensors = [path_to_tensor(img_path) for img_path in tqdm(img_paths)]
     14     return np.vstack(list_of_tensors)

<ipython-input-149-36af157e68bd> in path_to_tensor(img_path)
      4 def path_to_tensor(img_path):
      5     
----> 6     img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
      7     
      8     x = image.img_to_array(img)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    100         color_mode = 'grayscale'
    101     if pil_image is None:
--> 102         raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
    103                           'The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL.')
    104     img = pil_image.open(path)

ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL.
```

Comment: Are Keras and PIL in the same environment?

Comment: @DanielMöller I think they are

Comment: Have you tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124353/importerror-could-not-import-the-python-imaging-library-pil-required-to-load ?

Comment: @LucaMassaron Yes, I have tried these, including uninstall and then install pillow and install keras. And as I am doing thin on a new computer, there was no former python installed.

Comment: restart kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I just run into a problem like that. Then I install pillow and restart kernel(Spyder) to solve it.

Comment: Considering leaving this anecdotal answer as a comment on the question.