# Tensorflow import error when loading PIL (pillow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-imaging-library

I'm having an issue with my tensorflow on windows 10 (python 3.7, tf 2.1.0, keras 2.3.1, pillow 7.1.1). I had some code I wrote on an osx machine and was porting over to windows. I am using conda envs and have all the necessary packages installed (tensorflow, keras, pillow, opencv, etc) but I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
"...\venv\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py", line 108, in load_img
    raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `load_img` requires PIL.
```

I have tried reinstalling pillow, tensorflow, keras, creating a new environment, installing with pip and repeated this in about every location I can think of but this issue remains persistent. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment, how you created it, etc?

Answer (score 0):

One solution that might work for your case:

First, you need to : `pip install pillow` (uninstall + reinstall / upgrade it it's the case)

Second, you need to change your imports in this way:

```
from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image
```

This solution can be found in the following thread:

[ImportError: Could not import the Python Imaging Library (PIL) required to load image files on tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124353/importerror-could-not-import-the-python-imaging-library-pil-required-to-load)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have pillow installed (pip show pillow) and have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both using pip and in a conda env. I don't use the display function so I'm not sure why I need to import it? The error is occuring in a file that comes with Keras, its not anything I wrote.

Comment: I saw that post earlier but what was tried there didn't solve the error.

Comment: Please use tensorflow inside Keras rather than Keras alone. Replace all your imports to "from tensorflow.keras"